# NASM malloc returns NULL

Tags: malloc, nasm, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my attempts to learn NASM, I have tried to create a basic program to test `malloc` functionality. I have pasted it below:

```
bits 64

extern malloc

section .data

ARRAY_SIZE:             equ 27

array:                  dq 1

error_message:          db "Malloc returned NULL!", 10
error_message_length:   equ $ - error_message

section .text
global _start

_start:
    ; try to allocate an array of bytes in the heap memory using malloc
    push dword ARRAY_SIZE
    call malloc
    ;; if malloc returned NULL, throw an error
    cmp rax, 0
    je err_out
    mov [array], eax                ; save a pointer to the allocated memory in array

    ; fill the array with numbers equal to the indices at that location
    fill_for:
    xor edx, edx                    ; use edx for the for loop index
    .for_start:
    cmp edx, ARRAY_SIZE             ; break if edx >= BUFFER_SIZE
    jg .for_end
        mov [array + edx], edx      ; array[i] = i;
    inc edx
    .for_end:

    ; print the numbers in array
    print_for:
    xor edx, edx                    ; use edx for the for loop index
    .for_start:
    cmp edx, ARRAY_SIZE             ; break if edx >= BUFFER_SIZE
    jg .for_end
        mov eax, [array + edx]      ; print array[i]
        call print_small_number
    .for_end:

print_small_number:
; allocate stack space for the two-digit number string (two digit chars + '\0' = 3b)
;; save the old rbp
mov [rbp], rsp
sub rsp, 8
mov rbp, rsp
;; allocate space for the number string
sub rsp, 3
;; save rdx for the main function
sub rsp, 8
mov [rbp + 3], rdx

    ; turn the (assumed two-digit in base 10) number into a string in number_string
    ;; initialize the number to 0x30, 0x30, 0 (0x30 is the offset to turn a number into a base-10 digit; 10 = '\n')
    mov byte [rbp], 0x30
    mov byte [rbp + 1], 0x30
    mov byte [rbp + 2], 10
                                    ; the number to print is already in eax
    mov bl, 10                      ; divide the message length string by 10 to separate the 10s and 1s digits
    div bl                          ;; the quotient is the 10s digits and the remainder is the 1s
    add [rbp], al                   ; move the resulting char into the first slot in number_string
    add [rbp + 1], ah               ; move the resulting 1s digit char into the second slot in number_string

    ; print the message length string
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov rcx, rbp                    ; the string starts at rbp
    mov edx, 3                      ; two digits + \0 = 3 chars = 3b
    int 0x80

; return
;; restore the old rdx for the main function
mov rdx, [rbp + 3]
add rsp, 8
;; deallocate the number string
add rsp, 3
;; restore the old rbp
add rsp, 8
mov rbp, [rsp]
ret

err_out:
    ; print error_message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, error_message
    mov edx, error_message_length
    int 0x80

    ; end the program
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

However, when I call `malloc` from this basic NASM program, it's returning NULL (0), shown by printing out the following message:

```
Malloc returned NULL!
```

I am running this on a laptop with 6GB of RAM with few other applications open and I am only attempting to allocate 27 bytes, so running out of memory seems ridiculously unlikely.

I know that it may return NULL if the size parameter given is negative, but this is not the case as you can see in the code.

Does anyone have any advice? I don't understand why this malloc call could return NULL.

**EDIT:**

This example was assembled and run in 64-bit Linux Mint 17 Qiana using the following commands since a BASH script:

```
nasm -f elf64 "$1.asm" -l "$1.lst" &&
ld -s -o "$1" "$1.o" -lc &&
./"$1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `malloc()` should go into `rdi`, rather than be pushed onto the stack. It's probably failing because you're passing it `0`, or some extremely high number.

Also:

```
mov [array], eax
```

should be:

```
mov array, rax
```

since `malloc()` is quite capable of returning an address that won't fit into four bytes, and since `array` doesn't contain a valid memory address at that point, so you shouldn't indirect through it.

Comment: **x86_64** assembly uses a completely different **calling convention** than **x86** assembly. While all arguments in **x86** calls are pushed onto the stack, all **x86_64** arguments are placed in registers. (`RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9`, in that order)

Comment: The first six integer arguments are, at least, which at least the vast majority of the time will be all of them.

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried it out and it seems to have fixed it. That explains why all the examples I saw used the stack. Then, I wonder, what happens in x86_64 Assembly if you have a function that takes more than 6 arguments?

Comment: @REALDrummer: The remaining integral arguments then get passed via the stack.

Comment: The calling convention continues, but I don't have it committed to memory. (thanks Paul, I was just going to look that up)

Comment: Got it. Well, I'll be sure to look for x86_64 Assembly examples specifically from now on. I thought I must be doing something stupid. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: If you're wanting to learn 64 bit assembly with Linux, you can't go wrong with [Introduction to 64 Bit Assembly Programming for Linux and OS X](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Bit-Assembly-Programming-Linux/dp/1484921909/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428551645&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+64+bit).